# File in and file out in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i had created a python program but it was not working. this program would take in the input for a file and then display the file contents . the only error i was getting is a syntax error well i could not find the error . Please help me .
the code was :-

```
nm = input(“enter file name “)

str = raw_input(“enter ur text here: \n”)

f = open(nm,”w”)

f.write(str)

f.close()

print “1.See the file\n”

print “2.Exit\n”

s = input(“enter ur choice “)

if s == 1 :

    fi  = open(nm,”r”)

    cont  = fi.read()

for i in cont:

    print i

else :

    print “thank you “
```

Comment: What syntax error? And on which line? And where did you get those quotes from?

Comment: it was on line 10 or 11

Comment: it does not matters with quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading the filename using `input()` instead of `raw_input()`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5074256/1988505) that explains:

> If you use input, then the data you type is is interpreted as a Python
>   Expression which means that you end up with gawd knows what type of
>   object in your target variable, and a heck of a wide range of
>   exceptions that can be generated. So you should NOT use input unless
>   you're putting something in for temporary testing, to be used only by
>   someone who knows a bit about Python expressions.
>
> raw_input always returns a string because, heck, that's what you
>   always type in ... but then you can easily convert it to the specific
>   type you want, and catch the specific exceptions that may occur.
>   Hopefully with that explanation, it's a no-brainer to know which you
>   should use.

Also, since you are reading in the file contents by using `fi.read()`, your for loop `for i in cont:` will select each character of the file's contents one at a time, instead of each line. Something to be aware of!