# unexpected EOF while parsing error when taking input

Tags: python, eof, python-3.3

I have a very basic program that takes user input and reads it back to the user.
the code is:

```
x = input("hello what is your name: ")
print("hello " + x)
```

This works perfectly when run in idle however when run I run it by clicking on the file to get the command line type interface when I enter input i get the following error message:

```
    File "C:\Users\ROB\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in (module)
         x = input("hello what is your name: ")
    File "(string)", line 0

      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

can someone pleese explain why this happens and suggest a solution to enable me to take user input in the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Python 2, and are executing this somewhere with `stdin` closed:

```
>>> x = input("hello what is your name: ")
hello what is your name: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

On Python 2, use `raw_input()` instead, and run this in a terminal or Windows console, or from within IDLE.

Comment: Martijn thank you for a quick answer.your comment about me running python two made me relise that my proggrame was opening with the wrong launcher as i had python 2 updated to python 3 but did not delete python 2 meaning my code was running under python 2 even though i thought it was running under python 3

Answer (score 1):

#### See also

> [Python unexpected EOF while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing)

from the python docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> **input([prompt])**:
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.
>
> Consider using the **raw_input()** function for general input from users.