# Error whilst running Python .py files from terminal on Mac

Tags: python, terminal

I have a slight problem trying to run a python program from the terminal on my Mac. When my '.py' program has a **'input ("press the enter key to find out.")'** command the terminal gives the following error message once you've pressed the 'return' key.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "word_problems.py", line 6, in <module>
        input ("press the enter key to find out.")
      File "<string>", line 0

        ^
    SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Can someone explain where the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [Python unexpected EOF while parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing)

Comment: Thanks, I had looked around stackoverflow but hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 2.7, `input()` is identical to `eval(raw_input())`.

Thus, when you hit return, you actually enter `''`, and:

```
>>> eval('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<PythonForiOS-Input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

---

Instead, use `raw_input()`.

Comment: And yes, for all you observant people, I tested this on my phone :3.

Comment: @Hairdo. I guess I just tick the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use raw_input instead of input when you want accept string as an input. input takes only Python expressions and it does an eval on them.

Comment: Do you mean that in my original .py program I have to foresee the problem and use 'raw-input' each time, instead of the normal 'input' command? Isn't there any way around that as surely that means I make my program Terminal friendly only ....?

Comment: Great, tested it and it works fine. But as I said is there no other method? Of course it now works fine in Terminal, but I get the same error code in IDLE. The big difference is that at least I understand why. Big thanks.

Comment: Ok, I don't know if this is correct but ... I notice that if I add at the beginning of the program the command 'input=raw_input' everything works fine. This means you can switch it on and off with the '#' command when running your program depending on which Terminal or IDLE.