# My python program works fine in Windows 7 and prints to the console but gives an error in Linux Mint?

Tags: python, linux, windows

I am coding a program in windows. I started up my linux mint hardrive and for some reason it gives an error in the mint but not windows 7? Here are the 3 files of the program:

main.py:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        main.py
# Purpose:     An RPG (Roll playing game) where you wake up in a room and have
#              to figure out text based puzzles to escape.
#              The whole game will be done in a terminal (Shell) and will be
#              completely text and ascii code. This will be the main file.
#
# Author:      William Bryant
#
# Created:     15/12/2013
# Copyright:   (c) William Bryant 2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import time
import ascii
import quests

#The function that starts/restarts the game
def init():
    """
    Calls all the functions to start the game/ restart the game
    """
    #Display a cool banner
    ascii.ywu_banner(2)

    START_INPUT = input("Press ENTER/RETURN on your keyboard to start the game")
    time.sleep(0.7)
    ascii.clear()

    #Game text.
    game_text()

def options():
    pass
#The text which is the main story line after the banner which gives the player
#A sense of what the setting is about
def game_text():
    """
    Prints out a bit of text 2 lines down and clears the screen every 4 or so
    seconds.
    """
    time.sleep(5)

    print("\n\nYour eyes gentally and gradually, open")
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\nYou slowly gather your senses and sit up...")
    time.sleep(4.5)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\nYou look around the room, and try to make sense of the")
    print("environment you are in and to your surprise, you realise your in some")
    print("sort of a prison cell!")
    time.sleep(12.5)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\nYou place your hand on the wall...")
    time.sleep(3)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\n... It feels like some sort of metal.")
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print('\n\n"How did I get here?", \nYou think to yourself')
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    quests.way_out_quest()
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\nYou accepted the quest" + ascii.WOODEN_DOOR)
    time.sleep(10)
    ascii.clear()

    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\nYou see a wooden door next to your bed with 5 buttons and a handel...  " + ascii.WOODEN_DOOR)
    time.sleep(10)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\nYou the figure out that it's some sort of combination lock.")
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\nMmm, let me try this: ")
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

#if the file is the main file then start the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

quest.py:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        quests
# Purpose:     To contain quests functions for the game "Yoy wake up..."
#
# Author:      William Bryant
#
# Created:     17/12/2013
# Copyright:   (c) William Bryant 2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import time
import ascii
import main

#Error message if user executes the wrong file.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("[ERROR]: Do not run this file. Run main.py - this file should not be executed!")
    time.sleep(4)
    exit()

#Function for the first quest: do you want to find a way out?
def way_out_quest():
    """
    If the question is not answered, then the player can't move on. If they say
    yes, then they continue through the script. If they say no, then the init
    function is called from main.py
    """
    way_out_answered = False
    while way_out_answered == False:
        WAY_OUT_INPUT = input("Quest: Do you want to find a way out? ")
        if WAY_OUT_INPUT in ["yes", "Yes", "YES"]:
            way_out_answered = True


        elif WAY_OUT_INPUT in ["no", "No", "NO"]:
            way_out_answered = True
            time.sleep(2)
            ascii.clear()
            print("GAME\nOVER!")
            time.sleep (5)
            ascii.clear()
            main.init()

        else:
            print("Type yes or no. ")

        time.sleep(4)
```

ascii.py:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        ascii
# Purpose:     To create all the ascii art and graphic tools for the game:
#              "you wake up..."
#
# Author:      William Bryant
#
# Created:     15/12/2013
# Copyright:   (c) William 2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import time
import os

WOODEN_DOOR = """ ______________________________
/_____/_____/_____/_____/_____/
 ._.                    ._.
 | |                    | |
 |_|   ______   ______  |_|
 |-|  /__1__/  /__2__/  |-|         ___________
 | |                    | |         || ||| ||||
 |_|                    |_|         || ||| ||||
 ._.                    ._.         ||_||| ||||
 | |                    | |        _||_|||_||||_
 |_|   ______           |_|
 |-|  /__3__/           |-|
 | |              /\    | |
 |_|              \/    |_|
 ._.                    ._.                                     _____
 | |                    | |        ____________________________|_____|
 |_|   ______   ______  |_|       | |______________________________| |
 |-|  /__4__/  /__5__/  |-|       | |                              | |
 | |                    | |       |_|                              |_|
 |_|                    |_|
  _____________________________________________________________________
 /_____/  /_____/__/_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/
 /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/"""

#Error message if user executes the wrong file.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("[ERROR]: Do not run this file. Run main.py - this file should not be executed!")
    time.sleep(4)
    exit()

#Clear function
def clear():
    """
    Clears the console screen using the built in commands on a operating
    system (here linux and windows)
    """
    os.system(['clear','cls', "^L"][os.name == 'nt'])

#"Wake up..." title/banner at the start
def ywu_banner(num_of_times):
    """
    Prints You wake up...(the game name) in ascii code big letters into a
    console and clears the screen using the clear function above and reprints
    the message to make the dots at the end appear to be moving.
    """
    print("__     __                         _")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("\ \   / /                        | |")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) | _ _ ")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .__(_|_|_)")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("                                                  | |    ")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("                                                  |_| ")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    clear()

    for foo in range(num_of_times):
        print("__     __                         _")
        print("\ \   / /                        | |")
        print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
        print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
        print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) | _  ")
        print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .__(_|_)")
        print("                                                  | |    ")
        print("                                                  |_| ")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        clear()

        print("__     __                         _")
        print("\ \   / /                        | |")
        print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
        print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
        print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) |  ")
        print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .__(_)")
        print("                                                  | |    ")
        print("                                                  |_| ")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        clear()

        print("__     __                         _")
        print("\ \   / /                        | |")
        print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
        print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
        print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) |  ")
        print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .___/")
        print("                                                  | |    ")
        print("                                                  |_| ")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        clear()

        print("__     __                         _")
        print("\ \   / /                        | |")
        print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
        print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
        print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) | _ _ ")
        print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .__(_|_|_)")
        print("                                                  | |    ")
        print("                                                  |_| ")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        clear()
```

After the function ascii.ywu_banner(2) I use in main.py I get this error:

```
Press ENTER/RETURN on your keyboard to start the game
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 102, in <module>
    init()
  File "main.py", line 26, in init
    START_INPUT = input("Press ENTER/RETURN on your keyboard to start the game")
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running on Linux? Looks like it should be 3.x for the script to work.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing) says to use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: @Hersheezy : Python 2.x `raw_input()` became `input()` on 3.x.

Comment: Writing code that's compatible with both Python 2.x and 3.x is doable (I maintain and contribute to multiple projects that work on 2.6+/3.2+), but it's not exactly something you should be trying as a novice. Either get the same Python version on both platforms, or write 2.x code and then run it through `2to3` to automatically port it to 3.x.

Comment: 14 years old. That's awesome

Comment: Anyway, if you have a new-enough Mint, I think `sudo apt-get install python3` or `python3.3` will give you a Python 3.2 or 3.3; you will just have to run it with `python3` instead of `python` (because your default `python` always has to be 2.7; the system relies on it). In fact, you may already _have_ it installed; try `python3` and see what it does.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify which Python version(s) you were using, but I assume you have 3.x on Windows and 2.x on Linux. `input()` doen't work the same on Python 2.x and Python 3.x. On 2.x it tries to eval the user's input as Python code (which is very unsafe fwiw), which would explain your error if trying to run 3.x code on 2.x.

NB : the 2.x equivalent of 3.x `input()` is named `raw_input()` but you migh have a few other incompatibilites anyway.

Comment: desthuillier YAY -ty so much!