# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing in python

Tags: python

I am getting the above error in python.

```
w=[]
h=[]
l=int(input())
t=int(input())

for i in range(t):
    n=raw_input()
    w.append(n)
    n=int(input())
    h.append(n)

for i in range(t):
    if w<l and h<l:
        print ("UPLOAD ANOTHER")
    elif w>l and h>l and w!=h:
        print ("CROP IT")
    elif w>=l and h>=l and w==h:
        print("ACCEPTED")
```

Comment: Do you get the exception when first starting the script or when interacting with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing

Comment: Why are you using `input()` in one place and `raw_input()` in another?  You do know they are different, do you?

Answer (score 0):

You probably given a empty input or '\n' for the `n=int(input())` part. Try to give the number as input.

put this line in your terminal
`x = int(input())`. and give empty input, (just tap enter). vola..

`SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Answer (score 0):

You might be running the script on some online IDE. This also appeared to me while I was submitting my solution. The best way to deal with this is don't run your script on online ide rather directly submit it.

If the answer is correct it would get accepted else show the wrong answer.