# Python for Absolute Beginners: Chapter 2 #Word Problems

Tags: python, traceback

I've started working on the well known Python for Absolute Beginners 3e. I've been copying the code faithfully, but some how keep getting error messages. So, I used the code provided in the help/examples folder but still get the same message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word_problems.py", line 6, in <module>
    input("Press the enter key to find out.")
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Can someone give me either a clue, or explain what's not working. I can also post part of the code, the rest is identical (but I guess many people know this book), but with different questions:

```
print("If a 2000 pound pregnant hippo gives birth to a 100 pound calf,")
print("but then eats 50 pounds of food, how much does she weigh?")
input("Press the enter key to find out.")
print("2000 - 100 + 50 =", 2000 - 100 + 50)
```

Comment: that's because you're using `python 2`. Try  `raw_input()`

Comment: The point is, you should upgrade your Python version; you will no doubt encounter other inconsistencies later on.

Comment: Update to which one? I'm on Python 2.7, I have several courses which suggest staying with that version due to old programs they're using.

Answer (score 1):

use`raw_input` instead of `input`

> If you use `input`, then the data you type is is interpreted as a
>   Python Expression which means that you end up with gawd knows
>   what type of object in your target variable, and a heck of a wide
>   range of exceptions that can be generated. So you should NOT use `input`
>   unless you're putting something in for temporary testing, to be used
>   only by someone who knows a bit about Python expressions.
>
> `raw_input` always returns a string because, heck, that's what you
>   always type in ... but then you can easily convert it to the specific
>   type you want, and catch the specific exceptions that may occur.
>   Hopefully with that explanation, it's a no-brainer to know which you
>   should use.

[source 1](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1461_Python-input-v-raw-input.html) | [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about that! I did a Python course a few years ago, but had forgotten that detail, I just assumed the original code were correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using python2 version

so you raw_input() instead of input()

and your code should be:

```
print("If a 2000 pound pregnant hippo gives birth to a 100 pound calf,")
print("but then eats 50 pounds of food, how much does she weigh?")
raw_input("Press the enter key to find out.")
print("2000 - 100 + 50 =", 2000 - 100 + 50)
```

and If you want show output only on  blank input or enter,you can put simple validation as:

```
print("If a 2000 pound pregnant hippo gives birth to a 100 pound calf,")
print("but then eats 50 pounds of food, how much does she weigh?")
ur = raw_input("Press the enter key to find out.")

if ur== '':
    print "She weigh ", 2000 - 100 + 50,"pounds"
else:
    print 'SOrry!'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's because `input` in python 3 behaves like `raw_input` did in python 2. So one solution would be to use `raw_input` to get this to work in python 2.

However if you're following this book which seems like it's using python 3 I think you're much better off switching to python 3 now and you shouldn't run into these issues further along in the book.