# Python only works in one case, returns syntax error for other cases

Tags: python, syntax

The code works only for ip with two segments without a period at the end. (ex/123.4)
123.4.won't work;
123.4.5 won't work (even if there's period at the end)
I'm confused about what went wrong here.

so here's my code:

```
ip = str(input("Enter IP address:"))
if ip[-1] != ".":
    ip += "."

segment = 1
segment_length = 0

for character in ip:
    if character == ".":
        print "Segment {} contains {} characters".format(segment, segment_length)
        segment += 1
        segment_length = 0
    else:
        segment_length += 1







Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/jack1/Desktop/python_practice.py", line 1, in <module>
 ip = str(input("Enter IP address:"))
 File "<string>", line 1
  123.44.5
       ^
 SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Never could've thought that the error message is referring to input. Thank you!

Comment: this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing) talks about using raw-input rather than input, that could work...

Comment: @JianyuanChenJack presence of `input` call and string you actually passed in stacktrace is really contridactory with _never could've thought_, don't you think? ;)

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Yeah I should've put more thoughts into understanding what the error message is saying. This will be a good lesson for me, thanks!