# How to fix SyntaxError: invalid syntax on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python

I have code wrote on Windows, compiles and works correctly, but fails on the raspberry pi

wrote some simple test code to see if it spits out the same error

```
a = input('this is a test string to split at space \n').split()

print(a)
```

typed 15:00 (need this data point for the bigger project) and i got this error

```
15:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    a = input('this is a test string to split at : \n').split(':')
   File "<string>", line 1
    15:00
      ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

then tried 15 00 at the request of someone on discord, got this message

```
15 00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    a = input('this is a test string to split at : \n').split(':')
  File "<string>", line 1
    15 00
        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running different versions of python from windows to Raspberry Pi.

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing):

> Note: this is only for Python 2. For Python 3, raw_input() has become
>   plain input() and the Python 2 input() has been removed.

[Reference](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1461_Python-input-v-raw-input.html)

```
a = raw_input('this is a test string to split at space \n').split(':')

print(a)
```

[image]