# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing python error message

Tags: python

My code is simple. The problem is input command. 
I try to write python code that accept user string input from the keyboard and display it. But it Generate this error message always `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Generally my python code always can't accept user string input from the keyboard. any one can tell me the problem or fix this error message?

this is code

```
Message = input('> ')
Word = Message.split(' ')
print (Word)
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/My_Computer_Name/PycharmProjects/test/tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    message = input('> ')
  File "<string>", line 1
    Hi hi
        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: See [Python unexpected EOF while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5074225/4518341). You're running the code with Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: Tnxs it work 
i used "raw_input" instead of 'input'

Comment: You should switch to Python 3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using python 2.x so you would need to do:

```
Message = raw_input('> ')
Word = Message.split(' ')
print (Word)
```

I would definitely suggest upgrading to python 3.7 (3.8 is not supported for all packages).

Comment: Note the bullet point regarding questions that "have already been asked and answered many times before" in the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ah well.. good stuff then!