# Error occurred when using code-runner to run python file in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

It’s a very simple program which get user input and print it out in an infinite while loop, like this:

```
while True:
    s = input('Enter something: ')
    print(s)
```

But I got the following output when I typed “Hello world”:

```
Enter something: Hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chuyizhang/Documents/python/break.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = input('Enter something: ')
  File "<string>", line 1
    Hello world
              ^
  SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Or it could be:

```
Enter something: Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chuyizhang/Documents/python/break.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = input('Enter something: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Hello' is not defined
```

when I type “Hello”

And when I input three words or more I will get:

```
Enter something: Hello world hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chuyizhang/Documents/python/break.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = input('Enter something: ')
  File "<string>", line 1
    Hello world hello world
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So how can I fix it? Does it means that something is wrong with code-runner extension or vscode configuration?

Comment: Did you added python extension in your vscode?

Comment: @toRex I’ve already installed the python extension.

Comment: @EzzaldeenAlribi Just vscode, with code-runner extension to run the file.

Comment: Seems strange, have you tested it in terminal?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA The program works well in terminal.

Comment: Two steps you can do: restart your vscode and install python again in your platform. If already you have done it. Suggestions please run a signle print

Comment: @toRex I’ve already restarted vscode and it didn’t fix the problem. I’ve also disabled the python extension and reinstalled the code-runner extension and still got the same thing.

Comment: @toRex A single print works well. Things went wrong on input.

Comment: Now can you please it's indent ok or not.

Comment: @toRex Indentation is ok

Comment: Then try for the last

`pip install future` 
`from future.builtins import input` 
`str_value = input('Type something in: ')`

Comment: @toRex Do I really have to do the import? The program works well in command line. And I’ve already updated my question.

Comment: @toRex The link is useful. The program works when I use raw_input() instead of input(), so the python version is the cause of the problem. I modified the code runner compile command and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you face for `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. It may cause for many a reasons like version `conflict, indentation, syntaxt error etc`.

Your answer may be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing)